# Error response from Daemon: Container [] is not running- Creating channel error - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to solve the error described bellow. Any help would be appreciated.

Prerequisites: OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Cloned repository from git https://github.com/acloudfan/HLF-Windows-Fabric-Tool.git, working folder is HLF-Windows-Fabric-Tool,
Cygwin is used.

When trying to start the fabric network, the following message is received at channel creation:

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx
Error response from daemon: Container 2797d6ccdbc67cb438ad6e3da1147f0b1d645c0a9b9ae989aa9a544661579dd2 is not running
```

Other things to take into consideration: Symantec encryption is stopped ( Found it to be one of the reasons). Disk C is shared.

The container id in the error message cannot be started, and also has a different id on every run. Also, it is not found if running `docker -pf a`.

Here is how docker inspect over this container looks like for "State" quotes:

```
"State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 1,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2018-03-27T06:01:09.5383667Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2018-03-27T06:01:09.7187949Z"
    },
```

[screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zevcN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

check Your Peer container Logs.

1. Make sure the container volume path is set properly.
2. In windows container you have set the volume path as //D/rest of the path